# using symbols in xsl

Tags: xslt

i am using symbols `>` in xsl file , which work but when i am using like `<=` it shows nothing.

can anybody tell me , whats wrong with it `<=` and which alternative should i use?

```
<xsl:if test="price &lt; 100">
<xsl:if test="price > 100">
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two alternative solutions and an explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

The [W3C XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags) says that a literal `<` is not allowed in an attribute (`>` is OK):

> The replacement text of any entity referred to directly or indirectly in an attribute value must not contain a <.

So in the *test* attribute, you need to escape `<`. If your condition is `price <= 100` then you would write it as:

```
<xsl:if test="price &lt;= 100">
```

Comment: It is not true that the > character must be escaped. Read the Spec well (and of course, try it). :)

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: you are absolutely correct! I tried it as you suggested and, of course, it worked. I've updated my answer accordingly. Learn something new every day :)

Comment: Good. I am glad my answer was useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

An XSLT stylesheet must be a well-formed XML document. This is why the `<` character (and the `&` character) has to be escaped always when they are not in a CDATA section.

**Use either**:

```
<xsl:if test="price &lt;= 100">
```

or, if you don't like escaping:

```
<xsl:if test="not(price > 100)">
```

Comment: or `<xsl:if test="100 >= price">` for that matter ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should escape `<` to `&lt;`, as you have in your first code example.

The `>` escape is `&gt;`.

You should escape characters that have special meaning in XML - these are `<>"'&`.

Though in attributes, using `>` is fine.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters) SO question and answers.

Comment: if the condition is that price<=100   then nothing appears , so which symbol should i use for this

Comment: It is not true that the > character must be escaped. Read the Spec well (and of course, try it). :)